# How did I manage to make multiple field search query using Hasura GraphQL Engine?

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

Hasura is a game changer. When I started to use it was in its infancy stage of development but now it has got multiple customisable features and it allows to create custom postgres function and view. check  the below function which I wrote to manage to make multiple field search query using Hasura GraphQL Engine

1. I have made a custom postgres profile search function like below also this query allows to search array of elements.

```sql
CREATE 
OR 
replace FUNCTION search_profiles(
    _country text default null,
    _gender text default null,
    _marital_status text default null,
    _religion text[] default null,
    _age_start integer default null, 
    _age_end integer default null
) 
returns setof profile AS $$
SELECT * 
FROM   profile 
WHERE  ((extract( year FROM age(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, dob) ) >= _age_start 
AND    extract( year FROM age(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, dob) ) <= _age_end) OR _age_start IS NULL)
AND    (living_country LIKE _country OR _country IS NULL)
AND    (gender = _gender OR _gender IS NULL)
AND    (marital_status LIKE _marital_status OR _marital_status IS NULL)
AND    (religion IN  (select unnest(_religion)) OR _religion IS NULL)
$$ language sql stable;
```

2. the graphql query  must be like this

```
query searchProfileQuery {
  search_profiles(args: {
    _country: "United Kingdom",
    _gender: "male",
    _marital_status: "Un Married",
    _religion: "{hindu, muslim}",
    _age_start: 20, 
    _age_end: 29
  }, order_by: {created_at: asc}) {
    id
    income_currency
    last_name
    living_city
    living_country
    living_state
    marital_status
    mother_tongue
    nationality
    occupation
    religion
  }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, thanks for sharing. Have you had much experience trying to create a search query that weights columns differently yet?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet,